# Electrical and Control Engineering: Transfer Function Reduction problem

Tags: transfer-function

I am having a problem with calculating transfer function given with a picture below i need to calculate output Y(p) / input V(p) analitically.
Here are the equasions, i dont know the equasion for a and z
Y= fN = (F(p+r))N = F(P(z+m+f)+ROv)
p=P(z+m+f)
r = Ro=ROv
b = Bo=BOv
o = Ov
f = F(p+r)
m = M(b-a)
a = A ???
z = Z ???

Thanks for any help or comment[image]

Answer (score 2):

> *Thanks for any help or comment*

An initial helping hand but, the rest is up to you: -

[image]

Then try reducing the local feedback around P(p) and F(p) to something more manageable. Do it pictorially as I have done.

Comment: I need to solve this problem analytically not grafically as you have. With analytically i mean "methodically"

Comment: The method I've used is analytical. I've reduced the block in red to the smaller block analytically so I'm unsure what your expectations really are. My method is also "methodical". Are you saying that you can't see how I've made the above reduction analytically? Are you in fact expecting a full answer?

Comment: With analytically i mean using algebra methods. With algebra equasions i posted above

Comment: I used algebra to reduce the first block so I really don't know what you are expecting. Listen, this site isn't Chegg where you get homework answered on demand - you have to put some effort in and figure this out yourself (in the main). We only give hints here when asking homework questions and that is what I have done. If you expect a full answer then this is the wrong site for you @AncientOne

Comment: Y= fN = (F(p+r))N = F(P(z+m+f)+ROv) p=P(z+m+f) r = Ro=ROv b = Bo=BOv o = Ov f = F(p+r) m = M(b-a) a = A ??? z = Z ???

Comment: I mean using equasions above to find transfer function

Comment: @AncientOne I have solved the part I have reduced using simple algebra; it's up to you to take my lead and do the rest. If you can't understand what I've done above then please ask. There is absolutely no point in trying to do it as a whole without simplifying things in stages. That is called common-sense and, if you can't see that then try harder. I would also recommend you learn to use latex commands as per this: \$\dfrac{M}{1+A\cdot Z\cdot M}\$ = `\$\dfrac{M}{1+A\cdot Z\cdot M}\$`

Comment: Thank you for support